# In WPF how to determine how focus received

Tags: wpf, focus

I have a text box on a form and want to perform different actions when it receives focus depending on how the focus was received.

If the user clicks on the text box I want the standard method where the cursor is placed at the end of the text string inside the box.  If the user tabs to the text box I want all of the text contained within the text box to be selected.

Is there an elegant way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose one thing you could try would be to set some application-level (or parent-level) tunneling events so you can toggle a flag indicating it was mouse clicked or keyboard pressed (`PreviewMouseDown` and `PreviewKeyDown`).  Depending on what was previously pressed by checking that flag, you could do the appropriate action when the text box gets focus.

Comment: Actually, PreviewMouseDown is better to check for the textbox itself. But the rest is correct. Good answer!

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping to learn of an elegant solution where in handling the GotFocus or PreviewGotKeyboardFocus I could determine how it received focus.  I tried checked the KeyState for the Tab key, which works 90% of the time, but is a timing thing with whether or not the Tab key is still pressed at the time the focus event is handled.  I also intercepted KeyDown to handle the Tab myself, where I send the traversal request and then tell the next element to select it's test by the traversal request kept selecting the wrong item, it went to the parent and not the next child.

Comment: @WPFNewbie: You don't necessarily need to check if the key event came from the tab key, just that it was _a_ key.  These events are (for the most part) mutually exclusive so any key press came from a keyboard and any click came from a mouse.  Unless you set up alternative methods to change focus in your application, there is no way a mouse click would trigger the key event and vice versa.